# How to use a variable/Parameter with an IN clause in ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple select query:

```
SELECT A
FROM B
WHERE A IN :conditions
```

where `A` is a `char`.

If i do the full query as:

```
SELECT A
FROM B
WHERE A IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
```

it works

but if i use the parameter, when i try to execute with ORACLE SQL Developer i cannot get it to work.

I've already tried to submit the parameter as:

```
1* ('A','E','I','O','U')
2* 'A','E','I','O','U'
3* A,E,I,O,U
```

and query returns no results

What's the correct syntax to do so?

Thank U all

Answer (score 2):

You may use a substitution variable in SQL Developer (or in SQL* Plus). Use double quotes while defining.

Test data

```
create table b as select 'A' as a from dual union all 
select 'I' as a from dual union all
select 'U' as a from dual
```

Execution

```
define params = "'A','E','I','O','U'"
select A from B where A in (&params);
```

Result

```
old:select A from B where A in (&params)
new:select A from B where A in ('A','E','I','O','U')

A
-
A
I
U
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Thanks for your answer, but I just want to submit the parameter in the SQL Developer UI. I don't want to change the query.

Comment: @TiagoDias : Nowhere did I ask you to "change" your query. I told you to simply use a double quoted substitution parameter ( either by defining it or passing as user input )

Comment: I've been looking for a way to easily use variables in select statements in PL/SQL for years.  This is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

[Passing comma separated string as bind variable for VO query's IN operator](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/passing-comma-separated-string-as-bind-variable-for-vo-querys-in-operator-v2)

This problem vexed me for years before I discovered this solution.

I used this technique to build an object search at the CLI, where I pass in a list of schemas to a :BIND

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       object_type
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_name LIKE :SEARCH
   AND owner NOT IN (
    'SYS',
    'MDSYS',
    'DBSNMP',
    'SYSTEM',
    'DVSYS',
    'APEX_050100',
    'PUBLIC',
    'ORDS_METADATA',
    'APEX_LISTENER'
)
   AND object_type IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr(:bind_ename_comma_sep_list,'[^,]+',1,level)
      FROM dual CONNECT BY
        regexp_substr(:bind_ename_comma_sep_list,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
)
 ORDER BY owner,
          object_name,
          object_type;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I just want to submit the parameter in the SQL Developer UI. I don't want to change the query.

Comment: The UI includes an editor...where you write SQL...if you want to do this, you need to change your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a way to do it for Oracle based on this post:
https://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/08/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-an-in-clause/

Would be something like this:

```
SELECT A
FROM B
WHERE ',' || :conditions || ',' LIKE '%,' || A || ',%'
```

Probably it is not the best performance option but solves the issue